# Vue multiple select strange behaivour

Tags: select, vue.js, vuejs2

I have this template

```
         <select multiple v-model="selectedRows">
           <!-- availableFields -->
           <option v-for="row in availableFields" v-bind:value="row">
             {{ (row.data.title) }}
           </option>
          </select>
```

where selectedRows is empty array
availableFields is array filled by objects
Each row object has property data. For example

```
availableFields[i] = {
data: {title: "blablabla", type: "INDEX"}
}
```

, etc.

When i have objects with similar data.title,
a mouse click on one entity highlights all the others, which have the same title property.
On picture, if i click object with data.title = "newrow", second object with the same data.title is highlighted too.
[image]

Is it possible to fix this (i want to use multiple select)

Comment: can we see the method that chooses an item from availableFields and pushes it into selectedRows? if you are filtering only on the .title property, it would automatically push all objects with the same title

Comment: I'm able to reproduce your issue. I did not expect that behavior. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/yPQNaO?editors=1010

Comment: @LShapz OP is using Vue. There isn't a method; it's bound via `v-model`.

Comment: If we add any uniq property - all works - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wPQaew?editors=1010

Comment: @Bert oh yep, you're right (though ~technically there is a method somewhere in here https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/59dea374037ec2e6b1f5570a30774f2de0a44adc/src/platforms/web/compiler/directives/model.js )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting issue. I was able to reproduce the behavior you are seeing.

I expect the issue is because in HTML, `value` is a string and when the objects are converted into strings, they end up being identical strings, which is why they are *all* highlighted. Vue adds the actual `row` object as the property `_value`, which is why only a single value is added to `selectedFields`.

```js
console.clear()

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data:{
    selectedFields:[],
    availableFields:[
      {data: {title:"newrow", type:"INDEX"}},
      {data: {title:"newrow", type:"INDEX"}},
      {data: {title:"newrow", type:"INDEX"}},
      {data: {title:"newrow", type:"INDEX"}},
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.9/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select multiple v-model="selectedFields">
    <option v-for="row in availableFields" :value="row">{{row.data.title}}</option>
  </select>
  <hr>
  {{selectedFields}}
</div>
```

If you select one of the above items, *all* of them will be selected in the select (although only one is added to `selectedFields`. I wouldn't have expected this behavior because they are all separate objects, albeit with exactly the same properties.

One workaround is to add an `id` property to each object.

```js
console.clear()

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data:{
    selectedFields:[],
    availableFields:[
      {id: 1, data: {title:"newrow", type:"INDEX"}},
      {id: 2, data: {title:"newrow", type:"INDEX"}},
      {id: 3, data: {title:"newrow", type:"INDEX"}},
      {id: 4, data: {title:"newrow", type:"INDEX"}},
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.9/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select multiple v-model="selectedFields">
    <option v-for="row in availableFields" :value="row">{{row.data.title}}</option>
  </select>
  <hr>
  {{selectedFields}}
</div>
```

In this case, only the single selected object is highlighted.

In summary, to solve the issue, whether via @RoyJ's excellent suggestion using a computed, or by modifying the data, as long as there is some unique property that results in a different `value` string, the select should work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I was also able to reproduce the issue. If two entries have all the same fields, what's the difference between them? If you select one, it can be argued that they should all be selected. However, Vue doesn't actually add both to `selectedRows` consistently, so there's a bug however you look at it.

In my example below, I have changed `type` for one row, and you will notice that it selects independently of the others.

You can make a `computed` to give each entry a unique key. If you use `afWithKey` instead of `availableFields`, each selection affects only the selected row.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    availableFields: [{
      data: {
        title: "row",
        type: "INDEX"
      }
    }, {
      data: {
        title: "other",
        type: "INDEX"
      }
    }, {
      data: {
        title: "row",
        type: "INDEX2"
      }
    }, {
      data: {
        title: "row",
        type: "INDEX"
      }
    }],
    selectedRows: []
  },
  computed: {
    afWithKey() {
      return this.availableFields.map((e, i) => Object.assign({key: i}, e));
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select multiple v-model="selectedRows">
     <option v-for="row in availableFields" v-bind:value="row">
       {{ row.data.title }}
     </option>
   </select>
   <pre>{{JSON.stringify(selectedRows)}}</pre>
</div>
```

Another approach would be to use `index` as the value of the option and use a `computed` to turn the array of `selectedIndexes` into an array of `selectedRows`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    availableFields: [{
      data: {
        title: "row",
        type: "INDEX"
      }
    }, {
      data: {
        title: "other",
        type: "INDEX"
      }
    }, {
      data: {
        title: "row",
        type: "INDEX2"
      }
    }, {
      data: {
        title: "row",
        type: "INDEX"
      }
    }],
    selectedIndexes: []
  },
  computed: {
    selectedRows() {
      return this.selectedIndexes.map((i) => this.availableFields[i]);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select multiple v-model="selectedIndexes">
     <option v-for="row, index in availableFields" v-bind:value="index">
       {{ row.data.title }}
     </option>
   </select>
   <pre>{{JSON.stringify(selectedRows)}}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure its because the `value` of each option ends up being an identical string. Any unique property will result in a differing string.

Comment: Yes, I assume it works by stringifying. Which gives me another workaround idea.